# Incorrect number of probabilities using sample() for a simulation of a Markov Chain

Tags: r, simulation, markov-chains

I want to simulate a Markov Chain; nontheless, after running the "for" I receive the warning of *incorrect number of probabilities*. I don't know why I get it, nor how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
X <- NULL; n <- 100;
P <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
              0, 8/13, 3/13, 1/13, 1/13,
              1/16, 3/16, 3/8, 1/4, 1/8,
              0, 1/11, 4/11, 5/11, 1/11,
              0, 1/8, 1/2, 1/8, 1/4),
            byrow=T, nrow=5)

X[1] <- sample(c(0,0,0,0,1), 1);

for (i in 2:n){
   X[i] <- sample(c(0,0,0,0,1), 1, prob = P[X[i-1],])
}
```

The console throws me the following

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

Comment: `X[i-1]` can be 0. Then `P[X[i-1],]` would be an empty matrix. And that causes the error.

Comment: How can I solve it if my initial distribution is given by
`(0,0,0,0,1)`

Comment: @Roland thank you, I didn't think about that